# Sometimes I am getting 600 error in my Jmeter response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have observed sometimes I am getting `600 error code` in my jmeter response. I need help what was that and what things shall we implement to avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A bit more context could help, its really unclear to me currently.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP Status Code 600 is not [something defined by the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-status-codes), you need to consult your application developers and ask them what could be the cause of it.

I can think of the following possible reasons:

1. It happens due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter)
2. Your application gets overloaded and cannot handle the incoming requests properly, try [increasing the load gradually](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) and try to find the relationship between the number of users/request per second and presence of this error
3. You can add a Listener like Simple Data Writer to store request and response details, it might be the case you're sending a malformed request and application responds with 600 status code instead of normal [4xx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#client_error_responses)
4. Make sure to follow [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html) as it could also be the case JMeter fails to properly send the request due to bad configuration and/or lack of resources